# LINQ .NET 4.0 - WHERE alone OK - ORDERBY alone OK - WHERE and ORDERBY Fails

Tags: linq-to-objects

Below runs correctly without error:

```
IEnumerable<FieldDef> FieldDefQuery =
    from fds in FieldDefs 
    where fds.DispLevel == enumDispLevel.Grid     
    select fds;
```

Below runs correctly without error:

```
IEnumerable<FieldDef> FieldDefQuery =
    from fds in FieldDefs    
    orderby fds.DispOrder ascending 
    select fds;
```

Below fails:

```
IEnumerable<FieldDef> FieldDefQuery =
    from fds in FieldDefs 
    where fds.DispLevel == enumDispLevel.Grid    
    orderby fds.DispOrder ascending 
    select fds;
foreach (FieldDef fd in FieldDefQuery)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(fd.DispName);
}
```

With both where and orderby clauses it fails at execution time with the following message:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred
Parameter name: Parameter index is out of range.
   at Gabe2a.GabeLib.FieldDef.get_DispLevel() in 
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.<GetEnumerator>d__0.MoveNext()
```

I just cannot figure out how/why where-clause alone is fine and orderby-clause alone is fine but the two clauses together fail

Comment: What is `FieldDefs`? Could you post the code for the `DispLevel` property?

Comment: FieldDefs is a <List>FieldDef 
DispLevel is just a simply Byte property of FieldDef
public byte DispOrder { get { return dispOrder; } set { dispOrder = value; } }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is that LINQ queries are not evaluated until you enumerate through them. DispLevel could straight out `throw new Exception()` and the first two blocks, on their own, would cause no problems. When you get to the third block where you enumerate the query the exception gets thrown.

Look deeper into the DispLevel property and you'll find the cause of the problem.

Comment: Alternatively, add a `foreach` loop in the first two examples.

Comment: In the code there actually is a foreach loop in the first two examples (and does not error)